Adding 'pass' instruction breaks PyCharm iterating through a set
Found a strange behaviour with PyCharm in debugging mode.
Suppose we have a code:
a = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
for el in a:
    print(el)
    pass

If you but a break on a 'pass' line and try the code in debugging mode you got an error:
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

because the program tries to iterate through the cycle the fourth time.
But code works fine if you just run it (in working mode, not debugging) or remove the break from the 'pass' line (to the 'print' command for example).
Is it a PyCharm issue or I have some mistakes in a code?

pass doesn't create bytecode at which the debugger could break.

I am using PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Community Edition) and I cannot reproduce the problem.

Do you get this behaviour with exactly that code? It's important to make certain the issue is Reproducible ([mre])

Assuming you're running on Windows, the code 0xC0000005 represents an Access Violation. The code as shown and executed directly with your Python executable, is highly unlikely to produce that error. Try running the script from a command line. If it runs OK then the issue is almost certainly with PyCharm

@MatBailie: Yes, that exact code. That is why, as python programmers, we always want the OP to post the exact text of their program so we can see their exact problem.

@quamrana If there isn't a name mentioned, the comment is directed at the poster. So, I was asking the OP, not you. Why would I ask you to make sure the issue is Reproducible? ;)

Yes, this is the exact code, PyCharm 2022.3.3. Udated it to 2024.1, nothing changed. It seems this is the PyCharm issue

Ok, but what version of python are you using?

@quamrana 3.10.8

Ok, with PyCharm 2023.3.4 and python 3.10.8 I can reproduce your problem. Switching back to python 3.11 'fixes' the problem. I retracted my close vote.
